# Why did iTunes put some songs on an album under "Compilations"?

Tags: itunes, libraries

I added a new album to my iTunes library. 15 of the 17 tracks are listed under "Compilations" in the artist browser, while the other 2 are listed under the artist's name. I tried renaming the Artist and Album metadata, but it hasn't fixed the issue. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It didn't show this when I opened the info view for all of the files, but when I opened the info view for a single file, the check box for "This song is part of a compilation" was checked. I had to open the info view for each of the 15 songs that were listed as part of a compilation and uncheck that box.

Comment: Strange. Any idea why some songs got the compilation flag when you added them? Where were they originally imported from (downloaded, ripped from CD...)?

Comment: I had ripped them from a CD, but was moving them back onto a computer from an external HDD. I don't know why I would have marked these songs as a compilation, though. But I suppose at some point I did and didn't remember.